# Wget. Единый набор команд для полного скачивания сайтов

Tags: wget

Как должен выглядеть идеальный набор команд WGet для корректного скачивания сайтов. Мне нужна единая команда, где остается лишь менять необходимый сайт. Не знаю будет ли как-то конфликтовать если применить все нижеперечисленное, а так же необходимое по вашему мнению. [win10 wget 1.20.3x64]

```
1) wget -r -k -l 10 -p -E -nc --no-check-certificate -P C:\ [сам сайт]
2) wget --mirror --convert-links --html-extension --page-requisites --no-parent -P C:\ [сам сайт]
```

Чтобы скачать все изображения jpg с сайта: `wget -A "*.jpg"` (А как же css; png; jpeg; gif...) и куда-то правильно их расскладывать. Или стоит заменять index.html на файл загрузкой страницы через Ctrl+S.
`wget --user-agent=`
`-nc` [Если нужно догрузить все изменения сайта, когда он уже был скачан использовать это? Если файлы одинаково названы, то перезапишет ли он изменения в нем?]
...

Comment: команда Wget может скачивать только 1 файл и она ни чего не может узнать о содержимом сайта, а значит не может скачать его полностью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По моему опыту создать некий универсальный набор настроек для скачки сайтов нельзя, по крайней мере, если не выкачивать все сайты целиком. Дело в том, что структура сайтов может очень сильно различаться. Но можно использовать более-менее универсальный набор ключей который подходит в большинстве случаев, например я использую такой:

```
-c -nc -np -r -k -p -E
```

Для Windows можно использовать макросы doskey, для unix-систем - алиасы, либо создать файлы сценариев с настройками и коротким удобным именем для вызова, либо иной удобный для конкретного случая вариант.